# Draw arrow between two flex items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want the arrow to be inserted between two flex items as they are added(Please run the code). It must be added after the first flex item for every added flex item between them so that they appear connected by the arrow. The arrow must be at the midpoint of box boundaries ( not box centre) connecting them.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('text'))
    $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
});

$(document).on('click', '.flex-item' ,function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('flexActive')
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: green;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.flexActive{
  width:auto;
  display:block;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right:0;
}

ul li{
  display: inline;
}




.enlarge{
 zoom: 350%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">

<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>

<div class="enlarge">
<span>&#8674;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxNEjo

Comment: @MichaelCoker  add it as an answer. and remove the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element with the arrow as `content`, and to exclude it from the first element, use `:not()` in your CSS.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('text'))
    $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
});

$(document).on('click', '.flex-item' ,function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('flexActive')
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  /* Safari */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.flexActive {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.flex-item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: .75em;
}

.flex-item:not(:first-child):before {
  content: '\21E2';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container"></ul>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. What do i do if i want to have the arrow on first element beginning also? Just to make my concepts clear.

Comment: @darsh awesome, no problem. You would just remove the 2 instances of `:not(:first-child)` so the selectors would be `.flex-item { margin-left: .75em; }` and `.flex-item:before { content: '\21E2'; ... }` like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxNEME

Comment: Yea i read about it and figured it out. Thanks again! You are awesome:) @Michael Coker

Answer (score 2):

Remove the horizontal margins between your block elements, and then conditionally append the arrow before each inserted block when you detect that at least one block has already been added.

```js
var first = true

$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    var demos = $('#Demosss')
    if (!first) {
      demos.append('&#8674;')
    } else first = false
    demos.append($('<li class="flex-item">').text('text'))
    $(this).insertAfter($('.flex-item').last());
});

$(document).on('click', '.flex-item', function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('flexActive')
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: green;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.flexActive{
  width:auto;
  display:block;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right:0;
}

ul li{
  display: inline;
}




.enlarge{
 zoom: 350%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">

<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>

<div class="enlarge">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like this.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
      $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('text'))
      $('.enlarge').css('display','none');
      $('#Demosss').append($('<div class="enlarge1"><span>&#8674;</span></div>'))
      $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.flex-item' ,function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('flexActive')
  })
```

```css
.flex-container {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style: none;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
     flex-direction:  row;
     flex-wrap:  wrap;
 }
 .flex-item {
     background: green;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 100px;
     height: 150px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-right: 15px;
     line-height: 150px;
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 3em;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     
 }
 .flexActive{
   width:auto;
   display:block;
   flex: 1 1;
   margin-right:0;
 }

 ul li{
   display: inline;
 }


 .enlarge1{
  zoom: 350%;
 }

 .enlarge{
  zoom: 350%;
 }
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">

 <!-- add LI here -->
 </ul>


 <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
 <div class="enlarge"><span>&#8674;</span></div>
 <div class="arrow">
 </div>
```

Comment: This is another wayby using jquery. thank you. Btw your code needs some edit.